# How to wash long hair when making ghusl?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, wudu, ghusl, hair

I have long hair which I can't get cut due to barbers being closed due to COVID-19 Lockdown Restrictions. This makes it quite difficult for me to make ghusl since you have to make sure the water reaches the roots of your hair. This can make ghusl time-consuming and often means I don't have time to do ghusl As quick as I'd like. I do Ghusl in the shower (I don't have a bath) so my question is if there is any specific instruction for how hair is washed during ghusl? and how to do it quickly and efficiently.

Also for reference, my hair is long enough at the front to just cover my eyes and about halfway down the neck at the back so it's not super long.

Comment: What do you mean how? Just stand underneath the shower and rub with your fingers.

Comment: well yeah but it's kind of difficult to make sure it's completely reached my roots or that i've managed to rub all parts of my head

Comment: Ask your wife, mother, sister...

Comment: don't think I'd ask my mother or sister how to make ghusl...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine ladies have much more longer hair. All you have to do is put water three times on head and if you stand under shower 3 times for like 10 seconds each time; rubbing hair with fingers this will be done wetness will definitely reach roots of hair. From your description it feels you are over thinking and amount of effort mentioned above is sufficient.